# What's an alternative I could use instead of mp4v2/mpeg4ip?

Tags: software-recommendation, banshee

I've been looking for `mp4v2` and `mpeg4ip` - they are no longer in the multiverse repos in Oneiric.

I'm looking for something with equivalent functionality that I can use to give Banshee, Libgpod and GTKpod functionality to convert and put .m4v files on an iPod.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but 12.04 is due to be released soon. Looks as if these packages are in the precise repos (but not oneric).

At this late date, I would suggest you go with 12.04, it is a LTS and sue out shortly enough.